# Server not continuing after receiving request

Tags: erlang, client-server

When I run my server and client, the server receives a request but when the protocol/3 method is called, it just stops. I've checked with the debugger and it's just lands on the function call but nothing happens. A typical run at the moment looks like this:

```
server:start().

S = client:start().
client:authenticate(S, "Anon").
```

At this point it just stops working. Note that I run the server and the client on two separate erlang shells.

**Server code**

```
start() ->
    io:format("Starting Server..."),
    Clients = dict:new(),
    Database = spawn_link(fun() -> database(Clients)end),
    case gen_tcp:listen(1992, [binary, {active, false}]) of
        {ok, ListeningSocket} ->
            io:format("ok~n"),
            accept(ListeningSocket, Database),
            {ok, Port} = inet:port(ListeningSocket);
        {error, Reason} ->
            io:format("Failed: ~s", [Reason]),
            {error, Reason}
    end.

database(Clients) ->
receive
    {get_client, From, User} ->
        case dict:find(User, Clients) of
            {ok, UserSocket} ->
                From ! {id, UserSocket};
            error ->
                From ! error
        end,
        database(Clients);
    {ins_client, From, Socket, User} ->
        case dict:find(User, Clients) of
            {ok, _} ->
                From ! error;
            error ->
                Updated = dict:store(User, Socket, Clients),
                From ! ok,
                database(Updated)
        end
end.

accept(ListeningSocket, Database) ->
    io:format("Accepting..."),
    case gen_tcp:accept(ListeningSocket) of
        {ok, Socket} ->
            io:format("ok~n"),
            Pid = spawn(fun() -> loop(Socket, Database)end),
            gen_tcp:controlling_process(Socket, Pid);
        {error, Reason} ->
            io:format("Failed: ~s", [Reason])
    end,
    accept(ListeningSocket, Database).

loop(Socket, Database) ->
    inet:setopts(Socket, [{active, once}]),
    io:format("Waiting for request~n"),
    receive
        {tcp, Socket, Data} ->
            Request = binary_to_term(Data),
            protocol(Socket, Request, Database),
            loop(Socket, Database);
        {tcp_closed, Socket} ->
            io:format("Socket ~s closed. ~n", [Socket]),
            gen_tcp:close(Socket)
    end.

stop(Socket) ->
    gen_tcp:close(Socket).

protocol(Socket, Request, Database) ->
case Request of
    {message, To, Message} ->
        io:format("Message received: for ~s ~s", [To, Message]),
        Database ! {get_client, self(), To},
        receive
            {id, Receiver} ->
                gen_tcp:send(Receiver, term_to_binary(Message)),
                io:format("Sent to ~s: ~s~n", [Receiver, Message]);
            error ->
                gen_tcp:send(Socket, term_to_binary("User not found"))
        end;
    {enter, User} ->
        io:format("Request: {Enter: ~s}", User),
        Database ! {ins_client, self(), User},
        receive
            ok ->
                gen_tcp:send(Socket, term_to_binary("Authenticated"));
            error ->
                gen_tcp:send(Socket, term_to_binary("Authentication failed"))
        end;
    Other ->
        io:format("This happened: ~s", [Other])
end.
```

**Client Code**

```
start() ->
    io:format("Client starting..."),
    case gen_tcp:connect({127,0,0,1}, 1992, [binary, {active, false}]) of
        {ok, Socket} ->
            io:format("ok.\n"),
            spawn(fun() -> loop(Socket)end),
            Socket;
        {error, Reason} ->
            io:format("Failed: ~s", [Reason]),
            {error, Reason}
    end.

loop(Socket) ->
    inet:setopts(Socket, [{active, once}]),
    io:format("Waiting for data...~n"),
    receive
        {tcp_closed, Socket} ->
            io:format("Server ended connection.~n"),
            disconnect(Socket);
        {tcp, Socket, Data} ->
            io:format("From Server:' ~s' ~n", [Data])
    end.

authenticate(Socket, Username) ->
    inet:setopts(Socket, [{active, once}]),
    Term = {enter, Username},
    Request = term_to_binary(Term),
    gen_tcp:send(Socket, Request).

send(Socket, To, Input) ->
    inet:setopts(Socket, [{active, once}]),
    Message = term_to_binary({message, To, Input}),
    gen_tcp:send(Socket, Message).

disconnect(Socket) ->
    gen_tcp:close(Socket).
```

Sorry for any formatting errors, I'm still quite new to this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of your hang is that your `ins_client` message to your database process is missing the `Socket` element. The database process just ignores your incorrect `ins_client` message, leaving it in its message queue.

Some other things to fix:

- After accepting a connection, your server spawns a receive loop process and then transfers control of the new socket to that new process. It's better to spawn a new acceptor and just call loop directly, since that way there's no need to change the new socket's controlling process.

  ```
  accept(ListeningSocket, Database) ->
      io:format("Accepting..."),
      case gen_tcp:accept(ListeningSocket) of
          {ok, Socket} ->
              io:format("ok~n"),
              spawn(fun() -> accept(ListeningSocket, Database) end),
              loop(Socket, Database);
          {error, Reason} ->
              io:format("Failed: ~s", [Reason]),
              error(Reason)
      end.
  ```
- In your server `protocol` function you have an error in `io:format` where you're trying to print the user: the `User` argument needs to be in a list.
- Your `protocol` function is one big function with an internal case statement. It would be better written as multiple clauses, one for each expected message:

  ```
  protocol(Socket, {message, To, Message}, Database) ->
      io:format("Message received: for ~s ~s", [To, Message]),
      ...;
  protocol(Socket, {enter, User}, Database) ->
      io:format("Request: {Enter: ~s}", [User]),
      ...;
  protocol(_Socket, Other, _Database) ->
      io:format("This happened: ~s", [Other]).
  ```
- Your client's `loop` function is odd, since it's not a loop. It's more like a plain receiving function, so you might want to rename it.
- Calling `loop` from the `start` function is pointless because that newly-spawned process is not the controlling process for the socket, so it never receives anything.
- You should make the `loop` clause that handles `{tcp, Socket, Data}` return `Data`, so its caller can handle the returned data.
- It would be better if your client's `start` function returned `{ok, Socket}` for success rather than just `Socket`, as that makes it easier for the caller to distinguish between success and failure.

Comment: Thank you very much, I knew my problem my going to be something like this... Unfortunately it happens to everyone. Thank you so much for your answer as not only did you answer my question but you also helped me with the rest of my application. Greatly appreciated!

Comment: However, I had a question for the loop function. As you probably saw from my coding, I'm not a strong programmer in function programming and especially in Erlang. How can I make my client ready to not only function calls (from a user for instance), but also able to print out messages. Because I need to return the Socket to be able to use that specific client but I can't use print statements in in a spawned process.

Comment: To answer your question requires knowing if you expect your client to be able to receive messages not as a reply, but passively, like a server? If so, you should look into using a `gen_server` since it can take calls (such as calls to send something on the socket) while also listening for and handling incoming messages. This requires the `gen_server` process to be the controlling process for the socket. And btw, you can call `io:format` in a spawned process, but of course its output might get jumbled with output from other processes if they're trying to emit text concurrently.

Comment: Well my aim is to implement a server which is the middleman for the communication between one or multiple clients. This means that users will have the client and would be able to communicate with each other through the server.

Comment: What I am trying yo say is that I want the a client to be able to send messages, as well as receive them but not in a specific order. And for my server, I just need it to be in the middle, forwarding messages to clients that are connected to it.

Comment: You can either use a `gen_server` for your client as I mentioned earlier, or just make your client set `{active,once}` or `{active,N}` on the socket (where `N` is some number of messages to receive before going passive) and then have it occasionally check its message queue for messages and drain them if found.

Comment: Ok I will give both a try. Thank you 1000 times for your help again!